# How to measure system "cpu time and user cpu time" in Powershell for command execution?

Tags: unix, powershell

Measure-command wil give real time taken by the command execution in powershell.

I want to know user and system cpu times also for the command execution, like "Time Command" in powershell.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

That will be in the process information.  You can use

```
Get-Process -ID $PID
```

to get the process information for the current process.